# Install VMware : Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory. Please make sure that the kernel module `vmmon' is loaded

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware-workstation, uefi

I downloaded the VMware S/W from official website and installed the same. When I try to run any virtual machine it shows error

> Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory. Please make sure that the kernel module `vmmon' is loaded

and says `failed to initialize`.
I tried [this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=77363&start=15) solution and at the last command got the following error

```
$ sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
```

> EFI variables are not supported on this system``

Also I couldn't install the virtualbox as well, the error was

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Comment: What is your host OS, what kernel version etc

Comment: Output of `uname -a`     Linux Aspire-E5-573 4.4.0-119-generic #143-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 2 16:08:24 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 27):

There is a lot of posts about the missing vmmon, but this one always bites me after I update ubuntu kernel, and then I forget every time :)

From:
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1002411

`vmware-modconfig --console --install-all`

EDIT- I also have to do the following now on Ubuntu:

"First line only needs to be run once:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=VMware/"
sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
```

Then reboot and if memory serves you will asked to confirm a change to your boot loader. Essentially you are adding this self created cert to the boot loader.

```
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vmmon)

sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vmnet)

sudo modprobe -v vmmon

sudo modprobe -v vmnet

sudo vmware-networks --start
```

**You need to have the very latest version of workstation/player/viewer if you upgrade your kernel**
Workstation builds modules, and often the build process breaks if there are kernel changes. So if you are having problems first make sure you have the latest version of workstation https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-pro/workstation-pro-evaluation.html

Comment: After running the command, it shows Unable to start services

Comment: @Manthan Have you downloaded the latest version of Workstation / player?

Comment: `VMware Workstation 14.1.0 build-7370693` is the output for `$vmware -v`.

Comment: Latest is VMware Workstation 14.1.2 build-8497320
please update and try again

Comment: After running the command using 15.0.1 build-10737736 and linux kernel 4.18.0-15-generic in Kubuntu 18.10 I have Unable to start service Virtual machine monitor and Virtual ethernet

Comment: you might also refer to https://communities.vmware.com/thread/598913

Comment: in Manjaro to not get the error I have to run that `install-all` command each time I start the VM (or per boot, idk). I'm not even in UEFI boot mode. Whats up with that?

Comment: I got error 'Job for vmware.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status vmware.service" and "journalctl -xeu vmware.service" for details."  runnign command  ":vmware-modconfig --console --install-all"